# Python word counter sensitive to if word is surrounded by quotation marks?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter

I have a problem with my Python program. I am trying to make a word counter, an exercise from [Exercism](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/f33b5167ea1b4d14ae1ad01e9be42816).

Now, my program must pass 13 tests, all of which are diffrent strings with spaces, characters, digits, etc.
I used to have a problem because I would replace all non-letters and non-digits by a space. This created problem's for words like `"don't"`, because it would divided it into two strings, `don` and `t`. To counter this I added an `if` statement excluding single `'` marks from being replaced, which worked.

However, one of the strings I must test is `"Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."`. The problem is that since I exclude `'` markets, here `large` and `'large'` are considered as two different things, also they are the same word. How do I tell my program to "erase" quotes *surrounding* a word?

Here is my code, and I have added two scenarios, one being the string above, and the other being another string with only one `'` mark that you should not delete:

```
def word_count(phrase):
    count = {}
    for c in phrase:
        if not c.isalpha() and not c.isdigit() and c != "'":
            phrase = phrase.replace(c, " ")
    for word in phrase.lower().split():
        if word not in count:
            count[word] = 1
        else:
            count[word] += 1
    return count

print(word_count("Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."))
print(word_count("Don't delete that single quote!"))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check out [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.strip()` to take off the first and last characters once you have them in the list - https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html

```
def word_count(phrase):
    count = {}
    for c in phrase:
        if not c.isalpha() and not c.isdigit() and c != "'":
            phrase = phrase.replace(c, " ")
    print(phrase)
    for word in phrase.lower().split():
        word = word.strip("\'")
        if word not in count:
            count[word] = 1
        else:
            count[word] += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 3):

The module [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) holds some nice text constants - important for you would be `punctuation`. The module [collections holds Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) - a specialized dictionary class used to count things:

```
from collections import Counter 
from string import punctuation

# lookup in set is fastest 
ps = set(string.punctuation)  # "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~

def cleanSplitString(s):
    """cleans all punctualtion from the string s and returns split words."""
    return ''.join([m for m in s if m not in ps]).lower().split()

def word_count(sentence):
    return dict(Counter(cleanSplitString(sentence))) # return a "normal" dict

print(word_count("Joe can't tell between 'large' and large.")) 
print(word_count("Don't delete that single quote!"))
```

Output:

```
{'joe': 1, 'cant': 1, 'tell': 1, 'between': 1, 'large': 2, 'and': 1}
{'dont': 1, 'delete': 1, 'that': 1, 'single': 1, 'quote': 1}
```

---

If you want to keep the punctuations inside words, use:

```
def cleanSplitString_2(s):
    """Cleans all punctuations from start and end of words, keeps them if inside."""
    return [w.strip(punctuation) for w in s.lower().split()]
```

Output:

```
{'joe': 1, "can't": 1, 'tell': 1, 'between': 1, 'large': 2, 'and': 1}
{"don't": 1, 'delete': 1, 'that': 1, 'single': 1, 'quote': 1}
```

[Readup on `strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)